# Storing/Retrieving Dynamic Data in RavenDB

Tags: c#, dynamic, ravendb

I'm using RavenDB & need to store dynamic data like:

```
public class User {
    public string Name;
    public dynamic Data;
}
```

It appears that I could use many different types such as `dynamic`, `RavenJObject`,  `DynamicJsonObject`, `ExpandoObject`, `Dictionary<string, object>`, but I don't know what the differences are.

Could someone explain the options for dynamic data? I care less about querying & more about easy storage & retrieval.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Problem

Here's the deal, if you have a `dynamic` property then RavenDB will **always** deserialize it as a `RavenJObject`.  For example:

```
public class User {
    public dynamic Data = new ExpandoObject();
}

...

var user = new User();
user.Data.SomethingNew1 = "foo";
```

This looks harmless & works fine when you create your user. But when you **Load** user, RavenDB doesn't know what type you want for `dynamic` so it uses `RavenJObject`. You can't dynamically create properties (expando style) with `RavenJObject` so this fails:

```
var user = session.Find<User>(...);
user.Data.SomethingNew2 = "foo"; //compiles, but throws
```

### My Solution

Use an `ExpandoObject` and explicitly define its type in the property that is serialized.  That lets RavenDB (or JSON i guess) know what type you're expecting & it doesn't have to guess `RavenJObject`. Then, to keep your syntactical magic, wrap the property with a dynamic accessor.

```
public class User {
    public ExpandoObject _Data = new ExpandoObject();

    public dynamic Data {
        get { return _Data; }
    }
}
```

There are ways to make the expando object private & to create a setter for `Data`, but you get the idea.

### More Problems

Update: Unfortunately this solution exposes more problems. Say you store a list of strings in your dynamic data:

```
user.Data.Keys = new List<String>{"a","b","c"};
```

After you serialize/deserialize, JSON/Raven again doesn't know what type you are expecting. So if you try this (see below) then it compiles but you get a runtime exception *Cannot implicitly convert type 'Raven.Abstractions.Linq.DynamicList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'*:

```
List<string> keys = user.Data.Keys;
```

Answer (score 4):

For all of those, it doesn't really matter what your in memory type is.

object, dynamic and DynamicJsonObject are the same thing - as far as RavenDB is concerned. It gives you a 
dynamic implementation using RavenJObject as the backend for that.

RavenJObject is literally just the value that you get from the server.

ExpandoObject and Dictionary are serialized to/from dictionary, is all.